# phpliteadmin won't accept my directory

Tags: phpmyadmin, sqlite3

I have a system-wide apt install of phpliteadmin 1.9.8.2 on Ubuntu 22.10. In my `/etc/phpliteadmin.config.php` file I've tried to give a directory

```
$directory = '/home/homedir/Dropbox/org/databases';
```

but this produces

```
The directory you specified to scan for databases does not exist or is not a directory.
```

I assume this is some permissions problem? The directory does exist and has two sqlite databases in it.

Comment: Have you configured AppArmor to allow access to that directory?

Comment: Never heard of AppArmor. How would I do that?